# How i get only august month data from specific multi array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, filter

```
    $arr = [
        (Object)[
            'interval' => "2018-08-26",
            'product_id' => 12 ,
 'size' => 10 
        ],
        (Object)[
            'interval' => "2018-09-26",
            'product_id' => 26 ,
'size' => 25 
        ],
        (Object)[
            'interval' => "2018-07-26",
            'product_id' => 50 ,
'size' => 28 
        ],(Object)[
            'interval' => "2018-08-26",
            'product_id' => 60,
'size' => 89 
        ],
        (Object)[
            'interval' => "2018-12-26",
            'product_id' => 75,
'size' => 89 
        ],
        (Object)[
            'interval' => "2018-09-26",
            'product_id' => 98 ,
'size' => 89 
        ] 
    ];
```

I need only 12 and 60 product id. How can filter from this array (as only they has `interval` of Aug (**08**)).

Comment: id 16 doesnt exist in your array

Comment: What produced the output in your code example?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski its typo mistake this is 60 product id

Comment: `array_filter`?

Comment: Did you try anything? Even a simple foreach loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$arrays = array_filter($arrays,function($arr){
  return substr($arr->interval,5,2) == '08';
});

array_walk($arrays,function($obj){
  unset($obj->interval);
});
```

Comment: array_coloum is only fetch one key from object. I need 2 keys. product_id and size. Please check my question

Comment: updated my answer, sir!

Comment: Have you skype if yes then please give me

Answer (score 2):

If your input are IDs and you want to get dates then try

```
$ids = [12,60];

$result = array_filter($arr, function($e) use($ids) {
    return in_array($e->product_id, $ids);
});

$dates = array_map(function($e) { return $e->interval; }, $result );
```

working example [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a46aae78a3cb8fa8c25760ae971b81cc8b8a9c7a)

UPDATE

If your input is month number e.g. `08`  and you wana to get IDs then try this

```
$result = array_filter($arr, function($e) {
    return substr($e->interval,5,2) == '08';
});

$ids = array_map(function($e) { return $e->product_id; }, $result );
```

working example [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f50bc881eeecfd08ca69c1ad031c396bca771693). The `$result` contains full objects so you can read project_is as well as size.

Comment: Better define `$ids = [60,12]` and add `use ($ids)` and `in_array($e->product_id, $ids)` - but that just me...

Comment: you are correct but i need to get data from date not ids

Comment: @PriteshMahajan I update answer

Comment: i don't want to use ids :( @KamilKiełczewski

Comment: @PriteshMahajan If you don't want to use ids then you can use this return statement array filter: `return $e->product_id == 60 or $e->product_id==12;` and remove string `use($ids)` after function

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski, Please check my updated question

Comment: @PriteshMahajan I update answer